# update document in couchbase server 5.1.1

Tags: java, couchbase

I'm trying to update an object in couchbase server 5.1.1  .

additionalCodes is a list of object

```
Code(String code,String type,LocalDateTime datetime )
```

my object in couchbase is like this :

```
{
  "code": "code1";
  "creationDateTime": 1534852560000,
  "additionalCodes": [
    {
      "code": "code1",
      "type": "type1",
      "dateTime": 1534772384000
    }
  ]
}
```

and i do want to update this object like :

```
{
  "code": "code1";
  "creationDateTime": 1534852560000,
  "additionalCodes": [
    {
      "code": "code1",
      "type": "type1",
      "dateTime": 1534772384000
    },
    {
      "code": "code2",
      "type": "type2",
      "dateTime": 1534772384000
    }   
  ]
}
```

i'm trying this :

```
JsonDocument doc = bucket.get("ID");
doc.content().put("additionalCodes",new Code(...));
doc = bucket.upsert(doc);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the subdocument API? https://blog.couchbase.com/subdocument-couchbase-java-sdk/

Comment: Are you using KV only? what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this.  You can manually convert your object graph into corresponding Json* classes:

```
// Code code = new Code(...);
JsonDocument doc = bucket.get("ID");
JsonArray curAddlCodes = doc.content().getArray("additionalCodes");
JsonObject newCode = JsonObject.create()
    .put("code", code.code)
    .put("type", code.type)
    .put("dateTime", code.dateTime.toEpochSecond());
curAddlCodes.add(newCode);
doc = bucket.replace(doc);
```

Or you can use the subdoc API to efficiently update just the `additionalCodes` field, without having to fetch and send the full document:

```
bucket.mutateIn("ID")
    .arrayAppend("additionalCodes", newCode)
    .execute();
```

If you have a full object graph such as:

```
TopLevelCode(String code, LocalDateTime creationDateTime, List<Code> additionalCodes)
```

then you have a couple more options.  You can manipulate the POJOs are you wish, then serialize it to a JSON string using a library like Jackson, and store it in a RawJsonDocument:

```
// TopLevelCode tlc = new TopLevelCode(...)
ObjectMapper objectMapper = com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.JacksonTransformers.MAPPER;
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tlc);
RawJsonDocument doc = RawJsonDocument.create("ID", json);
bucket.replace(doc);
```

Or, if your object graph is Serializable, you could use SerializableDocument:

```
SerializableDocument doc = SerializableDocument.create("ID", tlc);
bucket.replace(doc);
```